# How do I re-set a BMP file's resolution (DPI) indicator?

Tags: java, image, graphics, resolution, bmp

I have a BMP tagged as 299 DPI resolution. I'd like to change that to 99 DPI.

Importantly, the DPI marker in a BMP has no structural meaning. An image has a certain width and height in *pixels*. The displaying application can show the image at any width in inches.

So, the DPI is just a hint.

However, I am dealing with some third-party software which behaves differently depending on this marker, so I need to re-set it.

I will appreciate suggestions on how to do this programmatically in Java, as well as in GUI graphics tools (e.g. Gimp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the Java part, you can use the [img4j](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/) library.
You have an encoder and a decoder for BMP. The [InfoHeader](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/javadoc/net/sf/image4j/codec/bmp/InfoHeader.html) class has a iXpixelsPerM and iYpixelsPerM to set the resolution. You chan check the BMP file format [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#DIB_Header_.28Bitmap_Information_Header.29) to have more information.

Moreover, as the library is opensource, you'll be able to check and understand how the code is working and you'll be able to adapt it to fit your needs (if it complies with your licensing model).

(Happy New Year! :)

Comment: Thank you. I think that the license won't allow it. Is this possible through the Java2D or other JDK APIs? It would also be easier to use an already-installed library.

Comment: Hi, due to the BMP file format being quite easy (check the link in my answer), you could easily write yourself a method to change this two particular values in the file header. I think it'll be the easiest way.
I don't think Java2D will allow you to do this but I may be wrong.

Comment: @LudoMC How do you set the iXpixelsPerM? I have tried by creating an InfoHeader() and setting it. Then re-assiging to the image. But no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In .Net you can set the DPI property of an image using the SetResolution method of the Bitmap class. Unfortunately I don't know how you can do it in Java. [**Update** the initial question asked for "how to do this programmatically (especially in Java)", this is why I mentioned the .Net solution.]

And here is how you can change the resolution property in GIMP: http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-print-size.html
In Paint .Net (free .Net based image editing tool) you would go to Image -> Resize -> Modify the resolution field.